# Can I fill a vessel with rigid bodies, animated?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I need to fill a tub with paper packaging. I don't care which method, whether it's simulation nodes, geo nodes, particles...
Everything is there in the blend file.

[Blend file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SgGdMFSPFNiNd1wEis8JHM9AG1YJMAOS/view?usp=sharing) 0[image]
[image: Blend file]

Answer (score 2):

You could create your container (object 1), an invisible funnel (object 2, give it an *Holdout* shader so that it makes object 3 invisible, you'll combine different view layers in the *Compositor*, and make it a rigid body passive), a series of paper packagings (object 3, active rigid bodies), and at last the box (object 4, rigid body passive):

[image]

Play the simulation:

[image]